# mod_rewrite rules not working as expected

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using the following code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  ^/(certain|folders|on|server) - [NC,L]
RewriteRule (.*) http://newserver/blog$1 [L,NS]
```

I would expect it to ignore my list of folders, and redirect to everything else. Instead, it seems to always be redirecting to "newserver". Changing the "-" to a URL in the first statement does work, but I don't actually want those folders directed anywhere.

Why does my statement not work as expected?

Also, I have noticed that for all the folders not listed, I have "newserver/", while the ones I listed are just "newserver" (no uri)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my rules do work as expected. I was previously trying using these rules in apache.conf. Moving it to the sites "VirtualDirectory" tag seemed to do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the leading slash in your rule. Rewrite rules in an htaccess file are given a URI to match against with the leading slash stripped off. Change your first rule by adding a `?` after the slash:

```
RewriteRule  ^/?(certain|folders|on|server) - [NC,L]
```

Or you can change it into a condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(certain|folders|on|server)
```

that will be applied to the rule that follows it.

Comment: I tried both of these, neither worked. For my first rule, it does match with the slash (replacing '-' with 'http://google.com' succeeded)